Getting the selected Cell on a not Active sheet
I'm trying to achieve that once I choose a cell in a Sheet, and then change to a different Sheet, I want a value from the 1st Sheet to be Pasted and linked into the selected cell in a 2nd Sheet.
Using methods getCurrentCell(); ActiveCell(); etc. won't help as they return the selected cell of the 2nd Sheet, which becomes an active one.
Is there a way to get the selection made in the 1st Sheet, which is currently not active?
Thanks
getCurrentCell(); ActiveCell();

It's not possible.
Workaround
Get the selection when the corresponding sheet is active.
